# how to receive signal from button in qml application

Tags: qt, qml

this is my first time using slider and i'm learning with this exemple . i'm trying to set up a slider controlled with 3 button , i have made 3 signal to emit slider state
but the probleme is the button are clickable and they send no signal to slider

```
VoletCommande.qml
Item {
    id: voletCommande

    signal shutterToMove(bool value)
    signal shutterToStop()
    signal shutterToSetAt(int value) //value(0 to 100)


    property int iSliderVoletMoving : 0
    property int iSliderValue : 25


    property string textVolet : ""


    property int fontSize : 10


    width: (parent.width-10) / 3
    height: parent.height - 15





    Rectangle
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "light blue"
        border.width: 0.5
        Text
         {
            text: textVolet
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 2
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.leftMargin: 2
            color: "gray"

            font.pointSize: fontSize
         }
        Rectangle
        {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height*2/3 - 1.5*fontSize
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 1.5*fontSize
            Image
            {
                id:imgVoletDown
                source: (iSliderVoletMoving == 2)? "qrc:/ShutterDownOn.png" : "qrc:/ShutterDownOff.png"
                width: parent.width / 3
                height: parent.height
                anchors.left: parent.left

                MouseArea
                {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked: {
                        shutterToMove(false);
                    }
                }

            }
            }
            Image
            {
                id:imgVoletStop
                source: (iSliderVoletMoving == 0) ? "qrc:/ShutterStopOn.png" :"qrc:/ShutterStopOff.png"
                width: parent.width / 3
                height: parent.height
                anchors.left: imgVoletDown.right
                MouseArea
                {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked: {
                        shutterToStop();
                    }

                }
             }
            Image
            {
                id:imgVoletUp
                source: (iSliderVoletMoving == 1) ? "qrc:/ShutterUpOn.png" : "qrc:/ShutterUpOff.png"
                width: parent.width / 3
                height: parent.height
                anchors.left: imgVoletStop.right

                MouseArea
                {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked: {
                        shutterToMove(true);


                    }
                }

            }

        }
        Rectangle
        {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height/3
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom


            Slider
            {
                id : sliderVolet
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                from: 0.0
                value: (iSliderValue / 100)
                to: parent.width * 3/4
                snapMode : Slider.SnapAlways
                stepSize : (to-from) / 20
                onMoved:
                    {
                        stutterToSetAt(100 * sliderVolet.value / sliderVolet.to);
                    }
            }
            Text {
                text: iSliderValue +"%"
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                anchors.left : sliderVolet.right
                anchors.leftMargin: 2
                color: "light blue"

                font.pointSize: fontSize*1.2
            }
        }
}

Volet.qml

Item {
    id : voletsTab

    signal shutterToMove1(bool value) 
    signal shutterToStop1()
    signal stutterToSetAt1(int value) //value(0 to 100)


    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin: 5
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 5
    property int fontSize : 10

    property int nbOfVolets : 1

    property int iSliderVolet1Moving : 0
    property int iSliderVolet1Value : 0 // en %
    property string textVolet1 : "VR1"

    property int iSliderVolet2Moving : 0
    property int iSliderVolet2Value : 0 // en %
    property string textVolet2 : "VR2"

    property int iSliderVolet3Moving : 0
    property int iSliderVolet3Value : 0 // en %
    property string textVolet3 : "VR3"



    Rectangle
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "transparent"
        border.width: 0.5
        Text
         {
            text: qsTr("VOLETS")
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 5
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 5
            color: "gray"

            font.pointSize: fontSize
         }

        VoletCommande
        {
            id : voletCommande1
            textVolet : textVolet1

            iSliderVoletMoving : iSliderVolet1Moving
            iSliderValue : iSliderVolet1Value // en %

            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 15
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: (nbOfVolets>=3) ? 5 : parent.width /(nbOfVolets*3)

            onShutterToMove:{shutterToMove1(value);}
            onShutterToStop:{shutterToStop1();}
            onStutterToSetAt:{stutterToSetAt1(value);}
        }

       

    }
}

mainpage.qml

Item{
 property int iSliderVolet1ValueSalon : 0
    property int iSliderVolet2ValueSalon : 0
    property int iSliderVolet3ValueSalon : 0

Rectangle
    {

        id: salonShuttertRec

        width: parent.width-90
        height:115
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.top: salonLightRec.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 5
        color: "transparent"
        border.color:"lightgrey"
        border.width:3
        radius: 5



        Volet
        {
            id : rectSalonTabVolets

            nbOfVolets :shutterSalon.count

            iSliderVolet1Value : iSliderVolet1ValueSalon
            iSliderVolet1Moving : iSliderVolet1MovingSalon
            textVolet1 : (nbOfVolets>0) ? shutterSalon.get(0).name : ""


         }
    }


}
```

i have done before i discovered signal , a function that decrease and increase slider value but i have to use signal to emit slider state to network system

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. It would help if you got rid of all the extraneous code and reduced your example to just the part that you need help with. It sounds like you want your buttons to send signals to your slider, but you're sending the signals to a parent object which I don't understand.

Comment: with voletCommande i made like the 3 button and their signal , and volet i just called signals ,but buttons do nothing and they are not clickable . i'm just learning signals with this exemple  , i'll appriciate if you could explain to me how could i change my code

Comment: When I see excessive anchoring, my first thought is you should be using RowLayout or ColumnLayout.

Comment: I tried running your code and found a typo: `onStutterToSetAt`->  `onShutterToSetAt`. I wasn't sure what I was doing wrong, because when I ran it, I couldn't make sense of what I was seeing. You definitely have way more lines of code to do something that should have been achieved with much less, so, definitely, there appears to be a case of overengineering. There's way more than signals happening here, so, it is really hard to advise on where to get started.

Comment: yep exactly , at first i used a normal function that was able to controle both slider by the three button (increase , decrease and stop ) so i  have not many problems, for onShutter signals i used them to replace my function ... my main idea for adding many signal is when i try to add more volets i'm hoping that every volet added could have its own signals ( is it good as an idea ) i know m doing many lines because im learning about this

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understanding the question, but, I wanted to share the following points:

- Avoid excessive anchoring by using `ColumnLayout` / `RowLayout` instead
- Consider replacing `Rectangle`+`Image`+`MouseArea` with a `Button` customized by setting `background` and `icon.source` property instead of
- Consider using `Frame` to wrap a child's geometry without needing to explicitly refer to the child's width/height (because Frame implicitly does this)
- Consider using `ListModel` to instantiate multiple copies of a delegate via either a `Repeater`, `ListView`, or equivalent
- Consider using `SVG` instead of `PNG` for image assets - can recolor via `icon.color` property

Here's a sample that demonstrates the above concepts:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    ListView {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: contentItem.childrenRect.width
        height: childrenRect.height
        spacing: 10
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { lbl: "VR1"; val: 25 }
            ListElement { lbl: "VR2"; val: 50 }
            ListElement { lbl: "VR3"; val: 75 }
        }
        delegate: Frame {
            background: Rectangle { }
            RowLayout {
                Label { text: lbl }
                VoletCommande { value: val }
            }
        }
    }
}

// VoletCommande.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
ColumnLayout {
    property alias value: slider.value
    RowLayout {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        AppButton { icon.source: "down.svg"; onClicked: value -= 5 }
        AppButton { icon.source: "stop.svg"; onClicked: value = 0 }
        AppButton { icon.source: "up.svg"; onClicked: value += 5 }
    }
    RowLayout {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        Slider {
            id: slider
            from: 0
            to: 100
            stepSize: 1
            snapMode: Slider.SnapAlways
        }
        Label { text: "%1 %".arg(slider.value) }
    }
}

// AppButton.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Button {
    icon.color: pressed ? "red" : "blue"
    icon.width: 32
    icon.height: 32
}

// stop.svg : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/square-32.svg
// down.svg : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/arrow-bold-down-32.svg
// up.svg : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/arrow-bold-up-32.svg
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)